# Update query with PDO throws error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get the hang of PDO but I'm getting the following error:

`Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`

Here's my code to update the `members` table

```
$firstname = ($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = ($_POST['lastname']);

$update = query("UPDATE members SET
firstname = '$firstname',
lastname = '$lastname', 
WHERE id = '$id'" ); 

$q = $conn->prepare($update);
$q->execute(array($firstname,$lastname));
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: try not to have string constant in multiple lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of parentheses around your variables makes them true/false which is not your intent.  Then, the whole point of using prepared statements is not to directly insert data into your queries, but instead either use ? or :someVariable so they will be properly escaped and can be used for multiple inserts.  Try something like the following:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$id = $_POST['id'];


$update = query("UPDATE members SET firstname = ?, lastname = ? WHERE id = ?"); 
$q = $conn->prepare($update);
$q->execute(array($firstname,$lastname,$id));

//OR

$update = query("UPDATE members SET firstname = :firstname , lastname = :lastname  WHERE id = :id"); 
$q = $conn->prepare($update);
$q->execute(array('firstname'=>$firstname,'lastname'=>$lastname,'id'=>$id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma where you shouldn't have one:

```
$update = query("UPDATE members SET
firstname = '$firstname',
lastname = '$lastname'  
WHERE id = '$id'" );
```

Should work, though I would use params in the prepared SQL statement.

```
$update = query("UPDATE members SET
firstname = :FirstName,
lastname = :LastName 
WHERE id = :ID" ); 

$q = $conn->prepare($update);
$q->execute(array(':FirstName' => $firstname, ':LastName' => $lastname, ':ID' => $ID));
```

Comment: Thanks, the comma was a typo when I copy pasted my code though, there's no comma in my source file.

Comment: @cali17 I updated the answer further with what I think you should be using - params and the prepared statement as shown. Not much point in preparing a statement if it already has the funky user entered data in it :)

Answer (score 0):

the parameters must be a key value array. string key being the associated parameter in the prepared sql.

```
$q->execute(array(
  'firstname' => $firstname,
  'lastname' => $lastname
));
```

and you're missing 'id' parameter

also, the parameters in the query should prefix with a colon

```
$update = query("UPDATE members SET
  firstname = :firstname,
  lastname = :lastname
  WHERE id = :id" );
```